# Open up Emacs in GUI instead of terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, emacs, gui

I downloaded Emacs in Linux 14.04, and when I type `emacs filename.c`, it opens Emacs in the terminal instead of the external Graphical User Interface. How do I force Emacs to open outside of the terminal?

Comment: Does your user account has permission to open the file? Have you tried `sudo emacs filename.c`?

Answer (score 2):

You can install `emacs-gtk` to have GUI support

```
sudo apt install emacs-gtk
```

This resolved this issue for me on linux mint (emacs26)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>or Emacs in a GUI type:</strike>

emacs -c

For an Emacs client in a GUI using a daemon:

```
emacs --daemon

emacsclient -c
```

**Update**

The '-c' option is for emacsclient and not emacs.

Comment: Emacs does not have a `-c` option by default.

Comment: `Unknown option ‘-c’`

Comment: that's correct I will edit the answer.

Comment: does not make a difference, still launches in terminal, and I know my Emacs could open as GUI as well, it just does not do it somehow

Answer (score 1):

Emacs typically comes in several flavors, where one is linked with the X11 libraries (which with all required dependencies becomes quite substantial) and one without so it can just run in a plain terminal like you see.

If the DISPLAY variable is set in the shell (which means an X11 server is available), which you can check with

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

then you need to install the Emacs that contains the GUI libraries.  If not, you should find out why not because then the Emacs you have might be fine, but just don't know how to reach the X11 server (the reason for this is that X11 supports going across the network, so clients need to know where to go)